# maven build works on windows but fails on linux

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have some project which is maven based.

the same project builds well on the windows but fails on the linux

Windows --------------- :

```
C:\project\code\microservice\ConfigService>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.conf:ConfigService >----------------------
[INFO] Building ConfigService 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 51 source files to C:\project\code\microservice\ConfigService\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\project\code\microservice\ConfigService\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default-jar) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\project\code\microservice\ConfigService\target\ConfigService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact C:\project\code\microservice\ConfigService\target\ConfigService-0.0.1-SNAPSHO
T.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.811 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-04T15:42:57+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Linux------------

```
user@myhost:~/project/work/ConfigService$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.conf:ConfigService >----------------------
[INFO] Building ConfigService 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/user/project/work/ConfigService/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ConfigService ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 51 source files to /home/user/project/work/ConfigService/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.479 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-04T05:28:06-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ConfigService: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So what would be the major cause for this issue, looks everything fine from other option

**On ubuntu I have Java version**

Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)
Maven home: /home/user/tools/maven/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

**On windows**

Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: C:\project\softs\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin..
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows

Comment: can you enable debugging and post the full trace?

Answer (score 0):

If the log you pasted is original then I could see that on linux path is not correct

```
/home/user/project/work/ConfigServicetarget/classes
```

After ConfigService it should use /

try to see in your files which config is missing or you need yo provide your source code.

Comment: I couldn't find this problem in the log. Which line number did you see this? I am having the opposite of this problem, on Linux the build passes, but fails on Windows, with the same error.